# Index of each matcher group of a pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am matching certain contents of a file against a regex and getting groups out of it. How can I get the start and the end positions of each matched group?
Need the positions to replace those parts
Any suggestions please ?

Comment: can you provide some example, like this no one can understand you

Comment: You don't need these positions and your approach is something of a hack.  `String#replaceAll()` can probably do what you have in mind.

Comment: @glearn - Your question is valid in my opinion, but the reason why you want it is bad. There are better ways to replace matched groups. But for those of us who actually need the group start and end positions, thank you for asking this question.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for methods `m.start(int groupId)` and `m.end(int groupId)`

Java Docs: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start(int)

In this case I would consider using named capture groups `(?<GROUP-NAME>YOUR_REGEX)` and methods `m.start("GROUP-NAME")` and `m.end("GROUP-NAME")`. This way when you change your input text or add/remove some groups, your group names are staying the same. :)

Answer (score 4):

The following code prints the text matching the regular expression and the start and end position within the text:

```
String text = "a long text regex to match";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("regex").matcher(text);

while (m.find()){
    String found = m.group();
    System.out.println(found + " " + m.start() + " " +  m.end());
}
```

Comment: I genuinely like downvotes when they have a comment with a clear explanation that let me understand what's wrong in my answer. So that I can learn and improve the answer and my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly replace your desired content with [replaceAll function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm):

> This method replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

Then, you can use it like:

```
replaceAll("[0-9]", "X");
```

Hope it helps you!